# ObjectContext ConnectionString Sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2010, connection-string, system.data.sqlite

I need to connect to a database in Sqlite so i downloaded and installed [System.Data.SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) and with the designer dragged all my tables.

The designer created a .cs file with

```
public class Entities : ObjectContext
```

and 3 **constructors**:

**1st**

```
public Entities() : base("name=Entities", "Entities")
```

this one load the connection string from App.config and **works fine.**

App.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Db.TracModel.csdl|res://*/Db.TracModel.ssdl|res://*/Db.TracModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite;provider connection string=&quot;data source=C:\Users\Filipe\Desktop\trac.db&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**2nd**

```
public Entities(string connectionString) : base(connectionString, "Entities")
```

**3rd**

```
public Entities(EntityConnection connection) : base(connection, "Entities")
```

**Here is the problem**, i already tried *n* configuration, already used EntityConnectionStringBuilder to make the connection string with no luck.

**Can you please point me in the right direction!?**

**EDIT(1)**

I can do my queries if i use de parameterless constructor but i need to change the connection string, i can't use the one in my app.config.

How can i construct a valid connection string?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Found it =)**

if you use the `EntityConnectionStringBuilder` to specify the `Metadata`and the `Provider` and use the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`to build the provider connection string and set the `DataSource` to your DB. **You can connect =)**

```
var con = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder()
  {
    Metadata = @"res://*/Db.TracModel.csdl|res://*/Db.TracModel.ssdl|res://*/Db.TracModel.msl",
    Provider = @"System.Data.SQLite",
    ProviderConnectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
      {
        DataSource = db,
      }.ConnectionString,
  };

connection = con.ConnectionString;
```